# Do Ostrich Eggs repel Spiders?

Tags: natural-remedies, entomology

After someone told me that Ostrich eggs repel Spiders I had to google it. I haven't been able to find a scientific explanation but throughout the Internet there are a lot of articles that mention it somewhere.

Also the [Wikipedia article about this Mosque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Ahmed_Mosque) mentions that Ostrich eggs were used to prevent cobwebs in the building.

Do Ostrich eggs really repel spiders? And if yes, why exactly?

Comment: Related: [Do horse chestnuts deter spiders?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23017/do-horse-chestnuts-deter-spiders)